# How to check the memory allocator used by my mysql 5.7.20

Tags: mysql

I am suspecting memory leak in my mysql 5.7.20 server as per below filed bug
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83047

So i installed jemalloc in my centos 7 server and rebooted mysql(service mysqld restart).
Now i wanted to check whether mysql has picked jemalloc as the mem allocator or not

I tried

```
pt-mysql-summary | grep -A5 -i "memory management"
Memory management library 
jemalloc is not enabled in mysql config for process with id 89539 The End
```

where can i check that information in running mysql instance?
Please help.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see which shared libaries mysqld has loaded with:

```
lsof -p $(pidof mysqld) | grep mem
```

If its using jemalloc it should be listed.